# How to Scroll to the Bottom of a ListBox when Items are Added

Tags: windows-phone-8, listbox

I'd like to be able to create some sort of auto scrolling feature in a ListBox I have, where new data is added periodically to the ListBox. Items populating the ListBox are held in an ObservableCollection, and are always added to the end of the collection. Is there a way to make the ListBox auto scroll to the bottom every time a new item is added to the ObservableCollection and the View is updated?

Comment: you could use ScrollIntoView() method to achive this

Comment: Is this supported in Windows Phone 8? I do not see it listed at the bottom of this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.scrollintoview(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;
listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
```