# How to Animate Items being Added to a ListBox

Tags: animation, windows-phone-8, listbox

In extension of the first question I asked here [How to Scroll to the Bottom of a ListBox when Items are Added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374331/how-to-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-listbox-when-items-are-added/22428773#22428773) where I discovered how to scroll a ListBox to the most recently added item, I'd like to be able to take this one step further and add in some sort of slide in animation to newly added items. How might this be possible? Any starting points would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Telerik's DataBoundListBox](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls/databoundlistbox.aspx), it supports add/remove animations in a easy declarative way.

Comment: Thanks, how might I accomplish this without a third party solution?